# How to use innerHTML to change a img with a class

Tags: javascript, html, class, innerhtml

I would like to change the `img` by using Ajax. But the console says "Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of undefined", and the `innerHTML` does not work properly. How can I change the `img` which has a class `type`?

```
       var pokeIcon = document.getElementsByClassName("type");
        for(var k=0; k < pokeIcon.length; k++){
            pokeIcon[i].innerHTML = "<img src=\"" + data.images.typeIcon + "\">";
        }
```

HTML is written below; (there are several elements which hace a class `type`, and so I cant use `id` for this.

```
<img src="icons/normal.jpg" alt="type" class="type"/>
```

Comment: You want `.src` not `.innerHTML`. if you want to change just the image path.

Comment: That's because you have a typo. Replace the `i` with `k` and then you'll get the element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two issues:

1. Your loop counter is `k`, but you're using `i` in the assignment
2. To change the `src` of an image, you change `src`, you don't use `innerHTML`

So:

```
var pokeIcon = document.getElementsByClassName("type");
for(var k=0; k < pokeIcon.length; k++){
    pokeIcon[k].src = data.images.typeIcon;
    // ------^--^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}
```

---

You question title is

> How to use innerHTML to change a img with a class

...so if that's **really** your question, the answer is: You can't reasonably do that. You'd have to set the `innerHTML` of the parent element, which would mean destroying and recreating all of its descendant elements (which would remove their event handlers, if they have any).

You might be able to do it with `outerHTML`, but `src` is the best way.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I maked to your answer!

Answer (score 1):

you must write "k" instead of "i"

Answer (score 1):

Do not use innerHTML for images.
Use .src for the same.

```
pokeIcon[k].src = data.images.typeIcon;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use query selector and src property.

```
var images = document.querySelectorAll('img.type');
var i = 0, limit = images.length;
for(i=0; i<limit; i++){
    images[i].src = data.images.typeIcon;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply set the `src` attribute, anyway the problem is that you are using the variable `k` for the loop and the variable `i` to set the image source.

To set src of image, see following please:

```js
var img = document.getElementsByClassName("type");
for(var k=0; k < img.length; k++){
    img[k].src = "http://www.maglioccola.com/images/stackoverflow.png";
}
```

```html
<img class="type">
```

I hope it helps you, bye.